# Recuperar el nombre del host y puerto del servidor, para utilizarlo como link en el cuerpo de un correo

Tags: java, aplicación-web

Tengo una aplicacion web que esta construida mediante servlets, y tengo un bean que es el encargado de enviar correos, y en estos se agrega un link para ingresar a cierta parte del sistema

```
 .append(servidor+"sisalbmReporte/grupos?action=vulnerabilidades&id=")
```

Pero estaba manejando el parámetro servidor de la siguiente forma:

```
private static final String servidor= "http://170.70.141.252:8080/
```

Pero mi aplicacion se va a subir a produccion y el area de servidores me comentan que ellos manejan clusters, por lo que esa declaracion de servidor me va a crear conflictos, de que manera puedo enviar el nombre del servidor y el puerto invariablemente del equipo en el que me encuentre.

Habia leido algo sobre HttpServletRequest:

```
 HttpServletRequest request;
 String serverName = request.getServerName();
 int portNumber = request.getServerPort();
```

Pero me marca NullPointerException no se que pueda hacer